# is not assignable to type 'string'. Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'string'

Tags: typescript

i'm learning ts, seriously, what's wrong with promises? :D

following function gives me this error

> Type 'string | void' is not assignable to type 'string'.   Type 'void'
>   is not assignable to type 'string'.

```
export async function getType(serviceID: string, vendor: string, {inventory = defaultKeyinventory } = {}): Promise<string | null>{

    const item= inventory !.getItem(serviceID, vendor)
        .catch(() => console.log('error'));

    return item;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.catch` returns a promise but you'll need to return something in your `catch` block. You'll need to return string or null.

```
export async function getType(
    serviceID: string, 
    vendor: string, 
    { inventory = defaultKeyinventory } = {}
): Promise<string | null>{

    const item= inventory !.getItem(serviceID, vendor)
        .catch(() => return null);

    return item;
}
```