# Type 'void | DiscordServer[]' is not assignable to type 'DiscordServer[]'

Tags: typescript, catch-block

I'm getting this error while trying to call an async function. This is my code:

```
let result:DiscordServer[]

result =  await Backendless.Data.of( backendlessDiscordServersTable! ).find<DiscordServer>( queryBuilder )
        .catch( e => writeDiscordLog(filename, functionName, errMsg, e.toString()))
```

And the interface for DiscordServer is:

```
export interface DiscordServer {
    objectId: string,
    created?: Date,
    ownerId?: string,
    server_id?: string,
    server_name?: string,
    updated?: Date
}
```

Now this question got me to the right track: [is not assignable to type 'string'. Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'string'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55436629/is-not-assignable-to-type-string-type-void-is-not-assignable-to-type-strin)
Basically I understand that I need to return something in the catch.

So I fixed it like this:

```
        result =  await Backendless.Data.of( backendlessDiscordServersTable! ).find<DiscordServer>( queryBuilder )
        .catch( e => {
            writeDiscordLog(filename, functionName, errMsg, e.toString())
            return result
        })
```

The error is gone, but I'm wondering if this solution is correct, should I be returning result?

*** EDIT ***
Just to clarify, what I'm not sure about is that when I return the var result inside a catch, what is it that I'm returning? Because if the function I'm calling is throwing an error, that error is returned in the catch. But result is of type DiscordServer[] so I'm not sure if I'll be having issues if the function throws an error and catch is executed. Hopefully I was able to explain my concern.

Also, as user kellys pointed out, I do have this code inside a try/catch block, I just wanted to simplify the code.

this is the code as I currently have it:

```
 try {
        result =  await Backendless.Data.of( backendlessDiscordServersTable! ).find<DiscordServer>( queryBuilder )
        .catch( e => {
            writeDiscordLog(filename, functionName, errMsg, e.toString())
            return result
        })
        if(result[0]){
            console.log(result[0].server_id)
            return result[0].server_id!
        }
        else{
            console.log('doesnt exist')
            return ''
        }

    } catch (error) {
        throw error
    }
```

Comment: Use a try-catch block perhaps

Comment: thank you @kellys, I have edited my question to be more specific.